# camel-example-cxf Not Deployed in ServiceMix 4.4.2

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, tomcat6, apache-servicemix

I was trying to run the camel-example-cxf example project which I downloaded from Camel website. (downloaded apache-camel-2.10.2)

I built the project using the pom.xml & the build was successful.
However when I tried to deploy it in servicemix (apache-servicemix-4.4.2) I am getting the following error.

```
karaf@root> ERROR: Bundle org.apache.camel.camel-example-cxf [43] Error starting file:/C:/apache-servicemix-4.4.2/deploy
/camel-example-cxf-2.10.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-example-cxf [43]: Unable to resolve 43.0: missing requirement [43.0] package; (&(package=org.apache.activemq.broker)(version>=5.7.0)(!(version>=6.0.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-example-cxf [43]: Unable to resolve 43.0: missing requirement [43.0] package; (&(package=org.apache.activemq.broker)(version>=5.7.0)(!(version>=6.0.0)))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3446)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1734)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1163)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Please help

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Hello Olle, I was trying to deploy the camel-example-cxf(which was part of camel 2.10.2 release) project into ServiceMix4.4.2 . But as Claus has answered below,it seems I have to download Camel 2.8.X. I am in the process of downloading it currently. I will post the results here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache ServiceMix 4.4.2 does not **support** Camel 2.10. You need to use the Camel version that it's shipped with, which is Camel 2.8.

Apache ServiceMix 4.5.0 will ship with Camel 2.10 and ActiveMQ 5.7. This release is in the works currently.

Comment: Thanks a ton Claus.Being last 8 years in java/j2ee stack, I have kinda habituated of getting backward compatibility for granted. Now I realize   that I should have been more careful when I am working on ServiceMix/Camel/CXF Stack space.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (but with activemq jar) and found that while running maven build i was using a different version than what servicemix had. you can find the version of jar file that are used by servicemix by using "exports" command (type export on servicemix command line) and you would come to know the version. if that is different than what you used for maven build then you would get that error. You have two option then
1. install different bundle in servicemix (with same version as used for maven build)
2. change the pom.xml to build maven build.